# Use Imacros to loop through files and folders on a screen

Tags: javascript, imacros

I have a file server that is accessed via a web browser! - don't ask :D

I have a very tedious task of going into every folder and downloading all the files in that folder, recreating the folder structure

In Psoudo
1) Open homepage
2) Scan links on the page for files and folders
3) download files for that page
4) open folder 
5) Repeat steps 2 to 4 until done

I have managed to get the imacros script to run and download each of the download links on the page

```
TAB T=1     

SET !LOOP 1
ONDOWNLOAD FOLDER=C:\downaloads\project FILE=* WAIT=YES

TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=A ATTR=HREF:https://url/view/objectId/*
```

I have done a fair amount of research and it works when playing as a loop, but i'm not sure how I can nest this loop for the folders - I have looked at Javascript but the tag position is not carried over to the next run of the download - so the same file is downloaded

Answer (score 1):

```
TAB T=1     

SET !LOOP 1
ONDOWNLOAD FOLDER=C:\downaloads\project FILE=links.csv WAIT=YES

TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=A ATTR=HREF:https://url/view/objectId/*  EXTRACT=HREF
```

Use this to scrape all the links from folder. Then navigate to those folders and scrape links until you reach to ALL links of the files.

Then you use a second macro that loads those links (from CSV file) 1 by 1 and goes to files and downloads them somewhere.

You have the basis of the second script. It's just a few more tweeks and it will work.